# Cannot convert <field> to excel

Tags: python, excel, error-handling, openpyxl, jira-rest-api

I am constantly running in this problem when importing fields to excel from JIRA rest API.

My output result is

```
[None,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 <JIRA Resolution: name='Fixed', id='1'>,
 None,
 None,
 <JIRA Resolution: name='Fixed', id='1'>,
 None,
 None,
 None,
 <JIRA Resolution: name='Done', id='10000'>,
 <JIRA Resolution: name='Done', id='10000'>,
 <JIRA Resolution: name='Done', id='10000'>,
 <JIRA Resolution: name='Done', id='10000'>,
```

This is my code below

```
res_list = []

issues_in_project = jira.search_issues('labels=team1', maxResults=False)


for issue in issues_in_project:
    res_list.append(issue.fields.resolution)

res_row = 2

for res in res_list:
    ws.cell(row=res_row, column=start_column+4).value = res
    res_row += 1
```

The error is

```
    217         elif value is not None:
--> 218             raise ValueError("Cannot convert {0!r} to Excel".format(value))
    219 
    220         self._value = value

ValueError: Cannot convert <JIRA Resolution: name='Fixed', id='1'> to Excel
```